# Detecting a missing sub!, sort!, map!, etc

Tags: ruby, warnings, lvalue, targetnullvalue

After returning to Ruby from a long stint coding in another language, I regularly assume that `foo.sort`, `foo.map {...}`, `foo.sub /bar/, 'zip'` will *change* foo.  Of course I meant `foo.sort!`, etc.  But that usually takes 3 or 4 debugging potshots before I notice.  Meanwhile, the sort is calculated, but then isn't assigned to anything.  Can I make ruby warn about that missing lvalue, like a C compiler warns of a function's ignored return value?

Comment: Figuring out whether a method returns a value or not is unfortunately equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **very** basic parser :

```
@forgetful_methods = %w(sort map sub)

Dir['*.rb'].each do |script|
  File.readlines(script).each.with_index(1) do |line, i|
    @forgetful_methods.each do |method|
      if line =~ /\.#{method}(?!!)/ && $` !~ /(=|\b(puts|print|return)\b|^#)/
        puts format('%-25s (%3d) : %s', script, i, line.strip)
      end
    end
  end
end

# =>
# brace_globbing.rb         ( 13) : subpatterns.map{|subpattern| explode_extglob(match.pre_match+subpattern+match.post_match)}.flatten
# delegate.rb               ( 11) : @targets.map { |t| t.send(m, *args) }
```

It checks every ruby script in the current directory for `sort`, `map` or `sub` without `!` that aren't preceded by `=`, `puts`, `print` or `return`.

It's just a start, but maybe it could help you find some of the low hanging fruits.
There are many false positives, though.

A more complex version could use abstract syntax trees, for example with [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html).

Comment: Mittag's "halting problem" comment, and tadman's concrete example, indeed suggest that low-hanging fruit is the best one can hope for.  A few false positives from such a test are tolerable.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like Perl's somewhat infamous "using `map` in void context"? I don't know of Ruby having such a thing. Sounds like you need more unit testing to catch mistakes like this before they can worm into your code deeply enough to be considered bugs.

Keep in mind Ruby's a lot more flexible than languages like Perl. For example, the following code *might* be useful:

```
def rewrite(list)
  list.map do |row|
    row += '!'
  end
end
```

Now technically that's a `map` in a void context, but because it's used as a return value it *might* be captured elsewhere. It's the responsibility of the caller to make use of it. Flagging the method itself for some sort of warning is a level removed from what most linting type tools can do.